# Use return value of a method as a service

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'd like to create a service for accessing Rackspace Cloud Files.  I've added the following configuration to `services.yml`:

```
services:
    # Rackspace
    # Note:  Rackspace parameters (e.g., %rackspace_username%, etc.) are set in
    #   app/config/parameters.yml.
    rackspace:
        class:  OpenCloud\Rackspace
        arguments:
            - "%rackspace_identity_endpoint%"
            - {"username": "%rackspace_username%", "apiKey": "%rackspace_api_key%"}

    rackspace.cloudfiles:
        parent: rackspace
        calls:
            - [objectStoreService, ["cloudFiles", '%rackspace_cloudfiles_region%', '%rackspace_url_type%']]
```

The `rackspace.cloudfiles` service doesn't work as desired, though, as I need the result of `objectStoreService()` (instance of `OpenCloud\ObjectStore\Service`), rather than the `OpenCloud\Rackspace` instance.

Is it possible to define a service from the result of calling `computeService()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the `rackspace` service as a factory:

```
services:
    # Rackspace
    # Note:  Rackspace parameters (e.g., %rackspace_username%, etc.) are set in
    #   app/config/parameters.yml.
    rackspace:
        class:  OpenCloud\Rackspace
        arguments:
            - "%rackspace_identity_endpoint%"
            - {"username": "%rackspace_username%", "apiKey": "%rackspace_api_key%"}

    rackspace.cloudfiles:
        class:              OpenCloud\ObjectStore\Service
        factory_service:    rackspace
        factory_method:     objectStoreService
        arguments:
            - "cloudFiles"
            - "%rackspace_cloudfiles_region%"
            - "%rackspace_url_type%"
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html for more info.